# Issue with image width CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a problem with my triangle buttons and it images.
Here you are the code >

```
[http://codepen.io/Luiggi/pen/elACq?editors=110][1]
```

Here you are an image to understand my problem. How to positioning the buttons and the image inside of it.[image]

I hhope that somebody can help me. Thanks a lot,

Luiggi

Comment: where do you want to position it?

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem. You image doesn't really help

Comment: You may set image height in CSS `img { height: 20px;}`

Comment: confusing questions only bring confusing answers at best ...

Comment: Sorry I need to positioning correctly the image that is inside of a green triangle . I hope that it's a layout problem

Comment: Why the image of the left triangle it's not equal than the right. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I hear you aright you need buttons like images?
For it you can use input with type button and src attribute.
Smth like the following:

```
<input type="image"  src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/150">
```

And then you have to position (I think absolute is better) them in container that wraps your image.
You will have smth like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="/i/image.jpg">
    <input type="image"  src="/i/btn1.png" class="btn1">
    <input type="image"  src="/i/btn1.png" class="btn2">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrapper { position: relative; }
.wrapper .btn1 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
.wrapper .btn2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
```